Playing PCM stream on Android with AudioTrack produces artifacts
I'm receiving PCM from a WebRTC native library wrapper, and trying to play it.
Here is my desktop JVM implementation, it works great, at least on Linux:
class NativeWebRTCClientDesktopImpl : NativeWebRTCClient() {

    private val audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()

    override fun onAudioReceivedInternal(data: ByteBuffer) {
        audioPlayer.onAudioReceivedInternal(data)
    }

    class AudioPlayer {
        private val audioLine: SourceDataLine

        private val sampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE
        private val channels = CHANNELS_COUNT
        private val bitsPerSample = BITS_PER_SAMPLE

        init {
            val format = AudioFormat(
                sampleRate.toFloat(),
                bitsPerSample,
                channels,
                true,
                false
            )

            audioLine = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format).apply {
                open(format)
                start()
            }
        }

        fun onAudioReceivedInternal(data: ByteBuffer) {
            val bytes = ByteArray(data.remaining())
            data.get(bytes)

            audioLine.write(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
        }

        fun cleanup() {
            audioLine.drain()
            audioLine.stop()
            audioLine.close()
        }
    }

    private companion object {
        private const val CHANNELS_COUNT = 2
        private const val SAMPLE_RATE = 48_000
        private const val BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 16
    }
}

But when I'm trying to play the same stream on Android with Android implementation, sound stutters and there is noise:
class NativeWebRTCClientAndroidImpl(
    private val audioManager: AudioManager,
) : NativeWebRTCClient() {
    private val logger = Logger.withTag(LOG_TAG)

    private val audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()

    override fun onAudioReceivedInternal(data: ByteBuffer) {
        audioPlayer.onAudioReceivedInternal(data)
    }

    private inner class AudioPlayer {

        private val frameSize = 960 // WebRTC frame size
        private val bytesPerFrame = frameSize * 2 * 2 // stereo * 16bit

        private val audioTrack: AudioTrack
        private val bufferSize: Int = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            CHANNEL_CONFIG,
            AUDIO_FORMAT
        )

        private val tempDataBuffer = ByteArray(TEMP_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE)
        private val dataBuffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
        private var currentBufferPosition = 0

        private var speakerDevice: AudioDeviceInfo? = null

        private val routingCallback = AudioTrack.OnRoutingChangedListener { forceSpeakerOutput() }


        init {
            logger.d { "Buffer size: $bufferSize" }

            val devices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)
            devices.forEach {
                logger.d { "Available device: ${it.type} - ${it.productName}" }
            }

            speakerDevice = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)
                .firstOrNull { device ->
                    device.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER
                }

            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                .build()

            val audioFormat = AudioFormat.Builder()
                .setSampleRate(SAMPLE_RATE)
                .setEncoding(AUDIO_FORMAT)
                .setChannelMask(CHANNEL_CONFIG)
                .build()

            audioTrack = AudioTrack.Builder()
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
                .setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize)
                .setTransferMode(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM)
                .build()

            audioTrack.addOnRoutingChangedListener(routingCallback, null)

            audioManager.apply {
                mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                isSpeakerphoneOn = true
            }

            speakerDevice?.let {
                if (!audioTrack.setPreferredDevice(it)) {
                    logger.e { "Failed to set ${it.type} as preferred device" }
                }
            }


            audioTrack.play()
        }

        private fun forceSpeakerOutput() {
            speakerDevice?.let { device ->
                if (audioTrack.preferredDevice?.id != device.id) {
                    audioTrack.preferredDevice = device
                }
            }
            audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
        }


        fun onAudioReceivedInternal(data: ByteBuffer) {
            val dataSize = data.remaining()
            data.get(tempDataBuffer, 0, dataSize)

            // I've also tried to simply do audioTrack.write() with the received data without buffering
            // Result is the same

            // The idea here was to wait until min buffer will be filled
            var offset = 0
            while (offset < dataSize) {
                val copyLength = minOf(bufferSize - currentBufferPosition, dataSize - offset)

                tempDataBuffer.copyInto(
                    dataBuffer,
                    currentBufferPosition,
                    offset,
                    offset + copyLength
                )

                currentBufferPosition += copyLength
                offset += copyLength

                logger.d { "Copied $copyLength to buffer, ${dataSize - offset} left" }

                if (currentBufferPosition == bufferSize) {
                    audioTrack.write(dataBuffer, 0, bufferSize, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING)
                    currentBufferPosition = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private companion object {
        private const val LOG_TAG = "NativeWebRTCClient"

        private const val SAMPLE_RATE = 48000
        private const val CHANNEL_CONFIG = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO
        private const val AUDIO_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT

        private const val TEMP_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 128
    }
}

Here is an example: https://soundcloud.com/art-s-394736082/webrtc?si=09d4bc30474b4ab7a965f30e3ff8b776
I've also tried this (as on C++ side it's int16_t):
fun onAudioReceivedInternal(data: ByteBuffer) {
    data.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)

    val shortBuffer = data.asShortBuffer()
    val shortArray = ShortArray(shortBuffer.remaining())
    shortBuffer.get(shortArray)

    audioTrack.write(shortArray, 0, shortArray.size, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING)
}

It's a bit better with fewer interruptions, but still very noisy with a lot of "cracks".
The audio format is correct.
What may be wrong?
UPD: Added a minimal demo: https://github.com/RankoR/android-pcm-experiments
It doesn't sound as bad as my WebRTC stream, but it has noticeable artifacts too.
UPD2: It's caused by underruns. In the demo above I've added underruns checks, and the number constantly grows.
If in the demo I replace Thread.sleep(sleepTime) with, for example, Thread.sleep(sleepTime / 2), it plays perfectly. But the demo plays pre-downloaded file, so I can write data at any speed.
And when I play frames from WebRTC stream I have to buffer some data to achieve the same. Does any simpler approach exist, like in desktop JVM example?
UPD3: I've tried many approaches and it's very difficult to synchronize timings to prevent underruns. I've solved my problem by moving audio rendering to Oboe with C++, it works perfectly.

The frame-size is wrong there, which causes buffer underrun:
// private val frameSize = 480 // samples per channel
private val frameSize = 2304 // these are actually the bytes per frame, per 2 channels

While this should better be calculated, based upon the parameters of the input format:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack#getBufferSizeInFrames()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat#getFrameSizeInBytes()
The downside is, that this is not backwards-compatible: AudioTrack.java#2241,
as someone already has asked for here.

There's even DSP StackExchange ...

It should be 1920 bytes: 480 samples per channel, for 16bit 2 channels it's 48022. audioFormat.frameSizeInBytes returns 4, so this calculation should be correct. If we use 2304, it means that one frame contains 576 samples, but that looks weird for 48 kHz with 10 ms interval

You're skipping the whole header, which has the parameters: Canonical WAV File Structure. Not exactly sure how the frame-size is being calculated, while it's basically: ByteRate = Bitrate/8.
